# Multi-information of a uniformly distributed random variable on the L1 sphere

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy, uniform-distribution, mutual-information

I posted this question in the stackexchange mathematics forum without any reponse. Maybe it was the wrong forum, so I try it here.

I tried to compute the multi-information (MI) $I[\mathbf U] = \sum_{i=1}^n H[U_i] - H[\mathbf U]$ of a uniformly distributed RV on the $L_1$ unit sphere. Below are my calculations. What confuses me is, that for $n=2$ the MI should be large since I can narrow down the value of $U_1$ to two possible values if I have $U_2$. However, my formula gives me zero. For larger values of $n$ it even becomes negative (which should not happen since the MI is always positive). What am I doing wrong?

**Calculations**
A uniformly distributed random variable on the $L_{1}$ unit sphere
has the stochastic representation $\boldsymbol{U}\stackrel{d}{=}\boldsymbol{Z}\odot\boldsymbol{X}$ ($\odot$ is the elementwise multiplication)
where $Z_{i}\in\{-1,1\}$, $Z_{i}$ Bernoulli with $p=\frac{1}{2}$,
and $\boldsymbol{X}$ has a Dirichlet distribution with parameters
$\alpha_{1}=...=\alpha_{n}=1$, and $\boldsymbol{Z}$ and $\boldsymbol{X}$ are independent.

To compute the multi-information of $\boldsymbol{U}$, I use the independence of $\boldsymbol{Z}$ and $\boldsymbol{X}$ to get
\begin{eqnarray*}
I\left[\boldsymbol{U}\right] & = & I\left[\boldsymbol{Z}\right]+I\left[\boldsymbol{X}\right] = I\left[\boldsymbol{X}\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
since the coefficients of $\boldsymbol{Z}$ are independent.

The marginal distribution of a the Dirichlet distribution is a $\beta$-distribution
with parameters $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=n-1$. Therefore, the marginal
entropy is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
H[X_{i}] & = & \log B(\alpha,\beta)-(\alpha-1)\psi\left(\alpha\right)-(\beta-1)\psi\left(\beta\right)+(\alpha+\beta-2)\psi(\alpha+\beta)\\
 & = & \log\frac{\Gamma\left(1\right)\Gamma\left(n-1\right)}{\Gamma\left(n\right)}-(n-2)\psi\left(n-1\right)+(n-2)\psi(n).
\end{eqnarray*}

The entropy of this particular Dirichlet distribution is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
H\left[\boldsymbol{X}\right] & = & \log\frac{\Gamma\left(1\right)^{n}}{\Gamma\left(n\right)}=-\log\Gamma\left(n\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
 Therefore, the multi-information is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
I\left[\boldsymbol{X}\right] & = & n\log\Gamma\left(n-1\right)-n\log\Gamma\left(n\right)-n(n-2)\psi\left(n-1\right)+n(n-2)\psi(n)+\log\Gamma\left(n\right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Dumb question, but can't mutual information be negative? At least that's what Wikipedia says: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_mutual_information I am not very informed about this myself. Also maybe phrasing the title as an "Entropy Calculation" or something like that might get the attention of people who are able to help you answer it even though they might not have previously encountered the concept of multi-information themselves? It's a good question, I'm not sure what the answer is myself.

Comment: Also this adds nothing to your question, but apparently the random variables $Z_i$'s can be said to have a Rademacher distribution: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution

Comment: No, the mutual information cannot be negative since it's the Kullback-Leibler divergence between the joint distribution and the product of its marginals. A KL-divergence is always non-negative.

Comment: OK, so to confirm, multi information (the topic of this question) is not the same as multivariate mutual information? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_mutual_information#Examples_of_negative_multivariate_mutual_information_(synergy) It looks like that's the case since that article doesn't mention KL divergence. Does $H$ here refer to $\int p(x) \log p(x) dx$ i.e. the entropy? I am trying to understand how the definition is a KL divergence, since I thought it was the difference of the entropies of the product distribution and of the joint distribution, which could differ from KL.